# Dynamic table filter for React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter

I have a react app in which I have created table rows and columns dynamically based on configuration data coming from the server.

Now I want to implement search functionality where I want to filter rows based on column values (one column can have combination of value i.e for the name it can be firstName + lastName)

So the idea here is to get the rendered value for that column and row and compare that with the searched key but how I can access the dynamically rendered column values, should I give some unique class or id to each row and column and access dom to read that value and do filter in react?

Comment: I think you need to provide some samples of screenshots of your tables. Cause it sounds like you need to re-render your table based on filter. For example you have array of elements that you want to render. You just filter elements in this array based on some condition and then pass filtered array as props to your table or update state with new array of elements

Comment: Please include some code.